# call a function with variable length of arguments

Tags: lua

In my lua script I need to call a function which takes an arbritary number of arguments with, well, an arbitrary number of arguments…

I am building up my arguments as a table as I cant know how many arguments there will be.

Sample code:

```
local result = call.someFunc();
local arguments = {}

for k,v in pairs(result) do
    table.insert(arguments, v.name)
end

-- here I would like to somehow pass the whole table and each item in the table
-- is then passed as a single argument to "someOtherFunc"
call.someOtherFunc(arguments[1], arguments[2], arguments[3] ....)
```

I am pretty new to lua, in PHP e. g. I would use [call_user_func_array](http://php.net/call_user_func_array) – is there something similiar in lua?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`foo(unpack(arguments))` is equivalent to `foo(arguments[1], arguments[2], ...)`.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I´ll accept this answer as soon as the system lets me. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

[The long answer](http://lua-users.org/wiki/VarargTheSecondClassCitizen) can be found on the Lua Users' Wiki.

This covers everything including trailing `nil` arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the table as the argument. No need to split it up into single arguments, just have the function loop through the table.